# Opening an html to a div with XMLHttpRequest causes sync error

Tags: html, ajax, asynchronous

I am trying to load a htm to a div in another htm but I keep getting the error below:

> Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

Here is my scenario:

**First.html (html)**

```
<div id="selectedPage"></div>
```

**First.html (script)**

```
<script>
function loadHTML2Div(htmlPage){
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200)
        {
            $("#selectedPage").html(xmlHttp.responseText);           
        }
    };

    xmlHttp.open("GET", htmlPage, true); // true for asynchronous
    xmlHttp.send(null);                
}


$(document).ready(function(){               
    loadHTML2Div("Second.htm");            
});
</script>
```

**Second.htm (html)**

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class='jumbotron'>
                <span>Verifique as datas disponíveis e agende seu evento.</span>
            </div>
            <div data-provide="calendar" id="calendar"></div> 
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="modal fade" id="preReservaModal">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                  <h4 class="modal-title" id="modaldate"></h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body ">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputNome">Nome Completo</label>
                        <input class="form-control" id="exampleInputNome" placeholder="Digite seu nome completo" type="nome">
                        <br/>
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email</label>
                        <input class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Digite seu email" type="email">
                        <br/>
                        <label for="exampleInputTelefone">Telefone para contato</label>
                        <input class="form-control" id="exampleInputTelefone" placeholder="Digite seu telefone para contato" type="telefone">
                        <br/>
                        <label for="exampleInputPlano">Pacote</label>
                        <select class="input-large form-control">
                            <option value="" selected="selected">Selecione um pacote</option>
                            <option value="DI" >Diamante</option>
                            <option value="ES">Esmeralda</option>
                            <option value="RU">Rubi</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                  <a href="#" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn">Fechar</a>
                  <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Confirmar</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src='bootstrap/js/bootstrap-combobox.js'></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap-year-calendar.js"></script>
</body>
```

I also have a navbar-nav from bootstrap on top of my First.htm for the navigation, and I also have a Third.htm and Fourth.htm that can be opened when the navbar is clicked. I use loadHTML2Div for switching between the contents of the . I don't know if this is the best approach.

As far as I searched this **Synchronous XMLHttpRequest** error, I would fix it by using ajax async call. I tried using xmlHttpRequest as mentioned above and I also tried using .ajax async

```
function loadHTML2Div(htmlPage){
    $.ajax({
        async: true,
        type: "GET",
        url: htmlPage,
        success: function(data){
            $("#selectedPage").html(data);
        }
    });               
}
```

But I got the same error.

Please advise me how can I avoid this sync error. As you can see I tried different ways before elaborating this question. 
If you need more information please let me know.

**Edited**
I kept testing and I fixed this error in some htmls. The problem was I was adding the Jquery and the bootstrap js in both First and Third html for example.
I removed the script declaration from the third.htm for example and left only the declaration in the 'upper' html (First.html). So somehow declaring it on both files was causing me the error.
Unfortunatelly, I still have a problem with the Second.htm which I copied to this question. This htm has a calendar and a bootstrap combobox. If I delete them from the Second.htm and write them in the First.htm, it doesn't work.

```
    <script src='bootstrap/js/bootstrap-combobox.js'></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap-year-calendar.js"></script>
```

I also have some scripts for the clickDay and setMinDate in the Second.htm as shown below which fail if I remove the scripts declaration and move it to the upper First.htm.

```
$('#calendar').data('calendar').setMinDate(todayDt);
```

So it seems to me my lack of knowledge is leading me to this problem. It is probably very simple to solve it, if someone could help me i will appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out what the problem was.
I moved the scripts declaration from Second.htm to First.htm

```
<script src='bootstrap/js/bootstrap-combobox.js'></script>
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap-year-calendar.js"></script>
```

Then I changed my html **from**

```
<div data-provide="calendar" id="calendar"></div>
```

**to**

```
<div id="calendar"></div>
```

and created the calendar in the ready function

```
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
            $('#calendar').calendar();
    });
</script>
```

As I am a newbie in web development, I know this is still not the best way to structure my website navigation using navbar from bootstrap. For now I will leave this way. 
My goal is to have my first htm with the navbar and the contents from each navbar item in different htms (as I have now), but I want the url to change as I click each item:

```
www.mywebsite.com/First.htm
www.mywebsite.com/Second.htm
www.mywebsite.com/Third.htm
```

And right now I only have

```
www.mywebsite.com/First.htm
```

Where all my scripts are included in the First.htm. It means I am loading the calendar.js even if I don't open the calendars page.

Well, I hope I will help someone with my question/answer in the future even though it is a little confusing. I promise next time I will have more knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

set your the ajax attribute `async` to false

```
$.ajax({
    async: false,
    type: "GET",
    url: htmlPage,
    success: function(data){
        $("#selectedPage").html(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Newbee, I tried that but I get the same error. Setting it to false makes all my pages generate that error by the way. When I set that to true, I only had the error on my calendar page. 

Please check my answer to that problem... It worked !! Probably not the best solution, but I believe I have bigger problems such as my navigation.

Comment: @FabioCarvalho still got the warning?

Comment: the error in fact is the warning `Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.` When I had this error my navigation stopped working and my modal pages stopped working too